# Encrypting text

Tags: security, encryption

I'm wondering if it's possible to encrypt text client side.

The situation is that I have a block of text I want to encrypt, and then save the encrypted text to a file. Only after a certain amount of time has passed will my program decrypt it. Another requirement I have is to be able to transfer the file with the encrypted text and be able to decrypt it with other copies of my program on various machines.

The problem is where to store the key. The only implementation I can think of that would work is if I store the key server side, and have it return the key after a certain time has passed.

Is there a way to do this client side (i.e. without any internet access)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surely encrypt text on the client side, but the real problem is key management.

If the assumption is no Internet access, then you're going to have to package a certificate in the client that contains *both* keys, private to encrypt, public to decrypt, unless you use a symmetric key. Was going to suggest just generating a local, temporary symmetric key, but you state you must be able to decrypt the text on other machines that won't have it, so that won't work. At first blush, and maybe I'm overlooking something obvious, is packaging a cert on the client with public and private keys, and that introduces its own set of problems, eg protecting the cert with the private key.